# Updating metadata in SharePoint Online via PowerShell using Excel sheet data

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-online

How to update metadata in sharepoint online via powershell script when all metadata ( name of document / number / etc.) is stored in excel document?

Result is a script which i can run on my pc that will update metadata. thanks.

Comment: Try and break your full solution down into parts. Asking us to build a Bike isn't going to work, but if you ask us how to repair the Chain or change the Battery we'll be able to help. Good luck, just dont expect so much.

Answer (score 0):

This article is about using PowerShell to read CSV files to update metadata：
[SharePoint Online: Bulk Update Metadata Properties from a CSV File using PowerShell](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2020/07/powershell-to-bulk-update-metadata-from-csv-in-sharepoint-online.html)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).